# Devise & warden failure_app not redirecting to custom path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to do some monitoring when user enters invalid login credentials and trying to use the `warder.failure_app` to do this as specified here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Redirect-to-new-registration-(sign-up)-path-if-unauthenticated.

However, the control never seems to come in my `CustomFailureApp` as i dont see the user redirected to the sign up page

below is the code i am using

```
lib/custom_failure_app.rb
class CustomFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  protected
  def route(scope)
    custom_logging
    :new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

```
application.rb
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

```
devise.rb

  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailureApp
  end
```

Any help in this would be great, how do i ensure that my CustomFailureApp is called and user is redirected to the registration page.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted the server after you added `CustomFailureApp`?

Comment: yes, have followed the instructions as specifed in the article

Comment: Have you tried replacing `custom_logging` with `puts "CUSTOM LOGGING TRIGGERED"` and verifying that it shows up in your server logs? This will make sure that your class is being loaded and that the `route` method is being called

Comment: hi @NMPennypacker, yes i have tried that as well, but commenting the `custom_logging` method call and replace it with `Rails.logger.error` statements, but i do not see it in the logs, I am also using `turbolinks` not sure if thats helpfull. But yes, i have tried logging too

Comment: Try it with `puts` and check the server logs

Comment: @NMPennypacker, tried it did not print anything

Comment: Well there you go. Your code isn't being called for some reason